# How does odd number print increasing order?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void Magic(int in);
int Even(int n);

int main()
{
    Magic(10);
}

void Magic(int in)
{
    if(in == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    if(Even(in))
    {
        printf("%i\n", in);
    }

    Magic(in - 1);

    if(!Even(in))
    {
        printf("%i\n", in);
    }
    return;
}

int Even(int n)
{
    return (n % 2) == 0 ? 1 : 0;
}
```

how does odd number print in increasing order?
It prints 10 8 6 4 2 1 3 5 7 9.
I know upto 10 8 6 4 2 but how come it prints 1 3 5 7 9? after decreasing order?

Comment: How come answers to this question were posted before the edit that made the question sane?

Comment: @MartinJames Why'd you rollback to the vandalized version? >.<

Comment: @MartinJames I rolled back your edit to a more appropriate version.

Comment: None of this makes any sense..   I think I'll get drunk now.

Comment: Sorry if I screwed up - I've only had half a bottle of Stoli

Answer (score 3):

There are nested calls `Magic(in - 1);`. If number is even it is printed immediately and then `Magic(in - 1);` is called. Only when `n` is zero all functions print not even number in reverse order. The first odd number is printed by the deepest `Magic()` function:

```
Magic(10)
   |print 10
   |Magic(9)
   |   |Magic(8)
   |   |    print 8
   |   |    ...
   |   |        Magic(1)
   |   |            Magic(0)
   |   |                return;
   |   |            print 1
   |   |            return
   |   |    ...
   |   |    return
   |   |print 9
   |   |return
   |return
```

Answer (score 0):

this is caused by the recursion of the function. the function is returning in the order it was called. if you want to print the odd numbers in decreasing order after the even numbers, you need to save them in a variable (array ) that is also passed to the magic function